# URL Rewrite like wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, permalinks

I have rewrite a url from:


`http://www.abc.com/page.php?id=3`


to:


`http://www.abc.com/page/3/`

The question now is how can I turn that id value '**3**' to be **aboutus**? (3 is representing 'aboutus' in mysql database)...How can we retrieve it and make it to be

`http://www.abc.com/page/aboutus/`

Something like wordpress url.

Please guide me.. really appreciate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+url+rewrite

Answer (score 2):

You could add a pageUrl into your database

Then to pass aboutus in your url:

```
http://www.abc.com/page/aboutus/
```

You would set it like:

```
$sql = 'select * from tbl_pages where id= 3';

...other bits....

$pageUrl = stripslashes( $row['pageUrl'] );

$url = 'http://website.com/page/' . $pageUrl . '/';
```

On page.php you would query `id` to the `pageUrl` field

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = 'select * from tbl_pages where pageUrl = "'.$id."';
```

To redirect your old url to your new url your probably using something like this in your Htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^page.php$ page/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

To turn this: `page.php?id=3` into `page/aboutus/` though you may have to create a landing page that uses the `id`, then gets the url from the database and forwards to that.

You Php landing page would look something like:

```
$sql = 'select * from tbl_pages where id= 3';

...other bits....

$pageUrl = stripslashes( $row['pageUrl'] );

header("HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: page/" . $pageUrl . "/");
exit;
```

Comment: can you write a little bit sample for the explaination.. I'm not too clear to your words.. very sry.. thanks for your patient my friend.

Comment: My friend I stucked at a problem before go on your sample code above, may I know how can I close my old url?
People can access new url only I mean.

Comment: Now both url also can enter right? I hope the new url can be enter only, if I enter old url then I will automatic go to new url.

Comment: When I go to old url it send me to this url...
http://www.abc.com/C:/wamp/www/abc.com/page/6/