# How to Assign a URL to Page in php from Database

Tags: php

I am trying to create something similar to a blogging script.

I have one question which i couldn't find on Stackoverflow.com

Suppose i have added Posts in my MySQL Database. And I am able to fetch them as well. But, How do I assign them their own unique page URL, and then fetch that particular post and display it on that page.

I want the URL to be similar to what is present in wordpress and other scripts.

Comment: `.htaccess` + `$_GET['article_id']`

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux Can you please elaborate a little more. I know about `.htaccess` and `$_GET`.

Comment: For the `.htaccess`, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426236/url-rewrite-like-wordpress

Comment: For the `$_GET`, @felipsmarins has a good answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming in your database there is a table called "posts" with an "id" column and a column "title", etc ... Then you could proceed like this:

```
<?php
$q = mysql_query('select id, title from posts') # select posts

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    //dumps article links
    echo sprintf("<a href='mysite.com/article.php?id=%s'>%s</a>", $row['id'], $row['title']);
}
?>
//so, at in article.php

<?php

$article_id = $_GET['id']; //Warning: filter user data

$article = mysql_query("select * from posts where id=$article_id") # select post by id collumn

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    //dump article content...    
}
```

Comment: This is fine. I am asking how to make the link `http://www.myurl.com/article_id/` or `http://myurl.com/article_title/`